# Where can I watch Starcraft/Starcraft 2 matches in South Korea live in person?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft

I am going to South Korea and would like to go to a taping or studio where they film Starcraft/Starcraft2 matches.  Could someone give me some insight in where I could make this happen?  I have googled it but havent had any luck.  Cheers

Comment: I'm forced to close your question as "too localized". Not only is where people can catch games going to change over time, but this information would be of no use to anyone not located in South Korea. Even then we would need to list locations near the area where you'll be staying, which makes the question even more localized. Please take the time to read our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Wipqozn, you're completely wrong. Not only have SC1 matches been held in the same area for something like the past decade, SC2 matches have exclusively been run by the same company in Korea for the duration of the game.

Comment: Ive always wondered this myself, good to know if I ever get to Korea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually really hard to find and as soon as I read the question I knew exactly the link I was looking for. Strange.

Anyway, here you go: http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=80483

SC2 matches are held here: http://www.gomtv.net/faq/view.gom?conid=60920, but if you want to see SC:BW  you'll have to use the above link. MBCGame no longer exists so you'll want to look into OGN to watch SC1 matches.

Comment: +1: I had the GOM-TV link in my bookmarks but you were faster =). I think this is the best possible answer.

Comment: I think this is the best answer.  I will be back to report if I figured it out.  Thank you kindly.

Comment: This information is accurate.  I went to the IMall Location and watched a Kart Rider Match and was on Korean TV.  The following day they were going to record the League of Legends show live on the air.  It was a really cool experience, you walk right in sit down and they had about 50 to 70 people for the KartRider.  Thank you for the great answer.